# Adding logo Image to <header> section but it appears in <main> section instead

Tags: html, image, header

I am trying to add a logo to my  section on HTML. Instead of the logo to be appropriately inserted into the header, it displayed in the  section.

I tried inserting the logo image logo to the  section, just to test it, but it appeared in the  section.

I am a newbie to HTML and coding in general. Please help me out, guys!

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <img src="images/mollay-removebg-preview.png" alt="Mollay Logo">
        </header>
        <nav></nav>

        <main></main>

        <footer></footer>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: All else being equal, that code will not have that effect. You don't even have a `<section>` element there! Possibly you have some CSS causing your problem but you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: You might also find [Use of ALT texts in IMGs](https://www.htmlhelp.com/feature/art3.htm) a worthwhile read. The pertinent information conveyed by a logo is not that it *is* a logo.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have to format its position and attributes in CSS.

```
header {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

This usually works for me but if u have more problems. Don't hesitate to let us know.